# Segment error initializing array of of File pointers

Tags: c++, unix, segmentation-fault, solaris

Can anyone please help me with the code below. I'm trying to create a bunch of pointers [pointer array] so that each would point to a new row in my file. Below is the code,it works fine for 4 iterations of reading first word from my file (i.e. first four lines are read correctly)and then errs out:

```
int main () {

    int num_row = 5;
    string line="";
    long len=0;
    unsigned long *Bpos = (unsigned long *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*num_row);
    int i = 0;

    //get the byte position for each of the row
     ifstream infile("out.txt");
     Bpos[i++]=0;
     while(getline(infile, line) ){
            len = strlen(line.c_str());
            Bpos[i++] = len+1;
            cout << i-1 << ": ";
            cout << Bpos[i-1] << ": " ;
            cout << line << endl;
    }

     char re[1000];// = char(*)malloc(sizeof([100];
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("out.txt", "r");
    FILE ** fRowPtr = (FILE **)malloc(sizeof(FILE *)*num_row*20);
    int rowInd = 0;
    long byteNum =0;

//open and initialize the row pointers
for(rowInd=1; rowInd < num_row; rowInd++)
{
   fRowPtr[rowInd] = fopen("out.txt", "r"); 
   if(fRowPtr[rowInd]!=NULL)
   { 
      fseek ( fRowPtr[rowInd] ,byteNum , SEEK_SET );
      byteNum += Bpos[rowInd];
      fgets(re,20,fRowPtr[rowInd]);
      cout << "word read : " << atof(re) << endl;
    }

 }
 return 0;

}
```

I make minor changes to the `cout` for `readword` and the error alternates between the `munmap_chunk()` or the segment error.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./i: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x09f5f020 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x188)[0x179b18]
/lib/libc.so.6(fclose+0x136)[0x167c96]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.
```

Valgrind Results

---

```
--19892-- Reading syms from /lib/libm-2.5.so (0xd6e000)
--19892-- Reading syms from /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1 (0x911000)
--19892--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--19892-- Reading syms from /lib/libc-2.5.so (0xc14000)
--19892-- REDIR: 0xc84540 (rindex) redirected to 0x4006550 (rindex)
--19892-- REDIR: 0xc853e0 (memset) redirected to 0x4006b80 (memset)
--19892-- REDIR: 0xc841a0 (strlen) redirected to 0x4006800 (strlen)
--19892-- REDIR: 0xc7fe30 (malloc) redirected to 0x400587e (malloc)
--19892-- REDIR: 0x4c45bd0 (operator new[](unsigned int)) redirected to 0x4005ca1 (operator new[](unsigned int))
--19892-- REDIR: 0xc858d0 (memcpy) redirected to 0x4007a70 (memcpy)
--19892-- REDIR: 0xc84ee0 (memchr) redirected to 0x40069f0 (memchr)
--19892-- REDIR: 0x4c45a90 (operator new(unsigned int)) redirected to 0x4006049 (operator new(unsigned int))
--19892-- REDIR: 0xc85440 (mempcpy) redirected to 0x40072d0 (mempcpy)
1: 22: 35.499645 239.034012
--19892-- REDIR: 0x4c44560 (operator delete(void*)) redirected to 0x40051af (operator delete(void*))
2: 23: 179.292328 160.118195
3: 21: 9.101529 272.455933
4: 23: 232.154388 135.067001
==19892== Invalid write of size 4
==19892==    at 0x8048CF4: main (fp2.cpp:22)
==19892==  Address 0x401b03c is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==19892==    at 0x4005903: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==19892==    by 0x8048C47: main (fp2.cpp:14)
==19892==
==19892== Invalid read of size 4
==19892==    at 0x8048D2F: main (fp2.cpp:24)
==19892==  Address 0x401b03c is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
```

Comment: Presumably you mean "segmentation fault". There is no such thing as a "segment" or a "segment error" in this context. What does _valgrind_ tell you? Also please format your question properly; the submission page has a preview pane.

Comment: my "out.txt" file looks like this:

Comment: Why all the ugly arrays and malloc? You're compiling C++, so write C++. You'll be happier for it.

Comment: thnx for the comment i'll replace it with new. though I dont think that wud fix the problem, let me see what Valgrind has to say

Comment: @Aks: It will if you made a bug in the hard-to-read `malloc` calls.

Comment: I'm not sure why Valgrind reports invalid reads and writes.

Comment: @Aks: Seriously, please format code and output when you post it. There's a "How To Format" box next to the textarea where you wrote it all.

Comment: @Aks: rather than replacing `malloc` with `new`, use containers like `std::vector` to manage memory for you. That will certainly fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you read more than 4 lines of input, you'll go past the end of `Bpos`, since you've only allocated 5 values.  The first iteration operated on index 1, so the 5th iteration operates on index 5, but the largest valid in index in that array is 4.

Also, this doesn't make sense, you're allocating 20 file pointers for each row:

```
FILE ** fRowPtr = (FILE **)malloc(sizeof(FILE *)*num_row*20);
```

And this will skip the first (`rowInd == 0`) item, is that what you want?

```
for(rowInd=1; rowInd < num_row; rowInd++)
```

Comment: thnx for ur comment, I adjusted the row_num to match the no of rows in my file. I still have the segment error. Skipping rowind 1 is fine. I'm trying to make the pointers point to the beg of each row. Allocating *20memory space was a desperate attempt to check for any memory shortage in allocating the pointer, I ahve that corrcted now. but I still get segment error

Comment: word read : 435.849
word read : 372.643
word read : 382.02
word read : 319.558
word read : 138.061
word read : 472.916
Segmentation fault

-my current o/p

Comment: Thank You so much folks!! I cud run my pgm (:

Comment: But `num_row` needs to be *more* than the number of rows in your file.  If you use a `vector<long>` you can just add however many rows you find rather than having to know how many rows to expect.

Comment: my num_row has to be 1 more than the no of rows.

Comment: And i read the no of rows from a temp file i had it hardcoded in this pgm as i isolated the error here